# Allow null for single date in Date range picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I am working with [angular-date rangepicker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker). For my requirement I need to have the option to set date as null for start date/end date or both. I looked into its option but didn't find any.

I also have the requirement to show checkbox in calendar popup to set `startDate` as null and checkbox for set `endDate` as null.

I found one plunker for setting null, but it sets both date as null/blank [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pQRfybEeltbjQi8FSlUZ?p=preview)

The plunker uses

```
 eventHandlers: {
      'cancel.daterangepicker': function(ev, ev1) {
        $scope.datePicker.date = {};
        // $scope.setRange();
        var picker = $element.find('#daterange4').data('daterangepicker');
        picker.setStartDate(new Date);
        picker.setEndDate(new Date);
      }
    }
```

That clears both date. In my case I want to have option to clear any one date.

Answer (score 2):

Prepare model in your controller. The model must have startDate and endDate attributes:

```
exampleApp.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
   //make initial values null
    $scope.datePicker.date = {startDate: null, endDate: null};

    //method to change start date back to null
    $scope.makeStartDateNull = function(){
        $scope.datePicker.date.startDate = null;
    }
}
```

In HTML you just bind this makeStartDateNull like

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="makeStartDateNull()" id="ng-change-example1" />`

You can do same for the end date.

Comment: ng-change="makeStartDateNull()" will work on change of value. I want to set conditionally using some input checkbox in calendar popup view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting it to null?
This is the [standard plunker as given by datepicker](https://plnkr.co/edit/261RKJA7GEufcAQtPCeY) with the option to set the date to null by:

```
  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };
```

It works on that plunker. 
I do know there was a bug in earlier versions of datepicker that did what you describe. Check your version.

Comment: Your given plunker is for single date picker and I am working on date-range-picker